# How to force load insecure content on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, insecure-connection

I want to force-load insecure content on IE. I do not want the user prompt to display insecure items or not. Is it possible to do that programatically through Javascript or some sort of header that browser understands?

I am working in IE browser.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're trying to do this on your own local computer (for testing purposes, for example) or on some other computer? The former question seems like a better fit for SuperUser, whereas the latter question is almost certainly a severe security risk.

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer, with default settings, will prompt you before displaying mixed secure and insecure content. To disable this feature, follow these steps:

1. From the Tools pull-down menu, select Internet Options
2. In the Internet Options dialog box, click on the Security tab
3. Click the Custom Level button near the bottom of the dialog box
4. In the Settings dialog box, scroll through the settings until you
   find the setting Display mixed content in the Miscellaneous section.
5. Change the default setting from Prompt to Enable
6. Click OK
7. Close the Internet Options dialog box by clicking OK

Answer (score 1):

I had answered these questions, which will help us in assisting you better.

Here are a few methods which you can follow to resolve the issue:

Method:

1. Start Internet Explorer.
2. On the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
3. Click the Advanced tab, and then locate the Security section.
4. Click to clear the Check for server certificate revocation check box, and then click OK.
5. Restart the computer.